# WPF Toolkit DataGrid Multi-Select: How to get SelectedItems out?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm using the WPF Toolkit's DataGrid. I've enabled the property on the DataGrid to allow for multi-selecting of rows. How do I get the SelectedItems out? I'm using an MVVM framework to bind my ViewModel to my View.

Thanks!

Comment: Answered partially by http://stackoverflow.com/a/2615487/284795

Answer (score 7):

Taking Bill's answer, merging options 1 and 2, adding a sprinkling of attached properties as an alternative to writing code-behind, I came up with a Behavior.

Firstly, we have the behavior:

```
Public Class SelectedItemsBehavior

    Public Shared ReadOnly SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItemsChangedHandler",
            GetType(mvvm.RelayCommand), GetType(SelectedItemsBehavior),
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnSelectedItemsChangedHandlerChanged)))




    Public Shared Function GetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(ByVal element As DependencyObject) As mvvm.RelayCommand
        If element Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("element")
        Return element.GetValue(SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(ByVal element As DependencyObject, ByVal value As mvvm.RelayCommand)
        If element Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("element")
        element.SetValue(SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnSelectedItemsChangedHandlerChanged(d As DependencyObject,
                                                            e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)

        Dim dataGrid As DataGrid = DirectCast(d, DataGrid)

        If e.OldValue Is Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler dataGrid.SelectionChanged, AddressOf ItemsControl_SelectionChanged
        End If

        If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue Is Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler dataGrid.SelectionChanged, AddressOf ItemsControl_SelectionChanged
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Shared Sub ItemsControl_SelectionChanged(sender As Object,
                                                    e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

        Dim dataGrid As DataGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGrid)

        Dim itemsChangedHandler As RelayCommand = GetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(dataGrid)

        itemsChangedHandler.Execute(dataGrid.SelectedItems)

    End Sub

End Class
```

C#:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class SelectedItemsBehavior
{


    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItemsChangedHandler", typeof(mvvm.RelayCommand), typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemsChangedHandlerChanged)));



    public static mvvm.RelayCommand GetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        return element.GetValue(SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(DependencyObject element, mvvm.RelayCommand value)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        element.SetValue(SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty, value);
    }


    private static void OnSelectedItemsChangedHandlerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)d;

        if (e.OldValue == null && e.NewValue != null) {
            dataGrid.SelectionChanged += ItemsControl_SelectionChanged;
        }

        if (e.OldValue != null && e.NewValue == null) {
            dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= ItemsControl_SelectionChanged;
        }

    }



    public static void ItemsControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        RelayCommand itemsChangedHandler = GetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(dataGrid);

        itemsChangedHandler.Execute(dataGrid.SelectedItems);

    }

}
```

Then we add it to the datagrid in XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultsVM}" 
          mvvm:SelectedItemsBehavior.SelectedItemsChangedHandler="{Binding Path=ResultsSelectionChangedCommand}" />
```

Then we code the RelayCommand in the ViewModel:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property ResultsSelectionChangedCommand() As mvvm.RelayCommand
        Get
            If _resultsSelectionChangedCommand Is Nothing Then
                _resultsSelectionChangedCommand = New mvvm.RelayCommand(AddressOf ResultsSelectionChanged)
            End If
            Return _resultsSelectionChangedCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ResultsSelectionChanged(ByVal selectedItems As Object)

        _resultsSelectedItems.Clear()
        For Each item In selectedItems
            _resultsSelectedItems.Add(item)
        Next

    End Sub
```

C#:

```
public mvvm.RelayCommand ResultsSelectionChangedCommand {
    get {
        if (_resultsSelectionChangedCommand == null) {
            _resultsSelectionChangedCommand = new mvvm.RelayCommand(ResultsSelectionChanged);
        }
        return _resultsSelectionChangedCommand;
    }
}


public void ResultsSelectionChanged(object selectedItems)
{
    _resultsSelectedItems.Clear();
    foreach (item in selectedItems) {
        _resultsSelectedItems.Add(item);
    }

}
```

The _resultsSelectedItems is simply a list of items displayed in the DataGrid:

```
    Private _resultsSelectedItems As New List(Of WorkOrderMatchViewModel)
```

C#:

```
private List<WorkOrderMatchViewModel> _resultsSelectedItems = new List<WorkOrderMatchViewModel>();
```

Hope this helps, kinda uses both of Bill's methods without having to reference MVVM-Light.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for an answer to this question as well. The answers that I have found is either to

1) in the codebehind delegate the work to a method in the ViewModel passing the `SelectedItems` list from the datagrid. This collection will contain all of the items that are selected.

Or

2) use the MVVM toolkit light that allows you to use Event to Command and pass an object as a parameter directly to the ViewModel.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IList lst = this.myDataGrid.SelectedItems;
    ViewModel.RowsSelected(lst);
}
```

In this case you will need to bind your `SelectionChanged` in your xaml to your `selectionchanged` in the code behind. Then in your code-behind you can save this list and use it for deleting selected rows, etc.

If there  is a better way to do this, I'd love to know is well.

HTH

Bill

Answer (score 3):

C# version SelectedItemsBehavior class. May be help someone.

```
 public static class SelectedItemsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItemsChangedHandler",
            typeof(RelayCommand),
            typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemsChangedHandlerChanged)));


    public static RelayCommand GetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        return element.GetValue(SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty) as RelayCommand;
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(DependencyObject element, RelayCommand value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        element.SetValue(SelectedItemsChangedHandlerProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnSelectedItemsChangedHandlerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)d;

        if (e.OldValue == null && e.NewValue != null)
        {
            dataGrid.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ItemsControl_SelectionChanged);
        }

        if (e.OldValue != null && e.NewValue == null)
        {
            dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ItemsControl_SelectionChanged);
        }
    }


    public static void ItemsControl_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        RelayCommand itemsChangedHandler = GetSelectedItemsChangedHandler(dataGrid);

        itemsChangedHandler.Execute(dataGrid.SelectedItems);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get around this using Relay Commands as Bill mentioned. It is a little dirty in parts, but I avoided putting any code in the behind file.

Firstly, in your XAML - Bind your command onto a button, or whatever triggers your RelayCommand.

```
<Button Content="Select" 
        cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding CommandSelect}"   
        cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Results, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

You'll notice the command parameter Binds to another UI element - the DataGrid or ListView you wish to get the selected items of. This syntax will work in Silverlight 3 as well as WPF, as it now supports element to element binding.

In your view model your Command will look something like this

```
Private _CommandSelect As RelayCommand(Of IEnumerable)

Public ReadOnly Property CommandSelect() As RelayCommand(Of IEnumerable)
    Get
        If _CommandSelect Is Nothing Then
            _CommandSelect = New RelayCommand(Of IEnumerable)(AddressOf CommandSelectExecuted, AddressOf CommandSelectCanExecute)
        End If
        Return _CommandSelect
    End Get
End Property


Private Function CommandSelectExecuted(ByVal parameter As IEnumerable) As Boolean

    For Each Item As IElectoralAreaNode In parameter

    Next

    Return True
End Function

Private Function CommandSelectCanExecute() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

The Selected Items will be returned as a SelectedItemCollection, but you probably don't want this dependancy in your View Model. So typing it as IEnumerable and doing a little casting is your only option, hense the 'dirtyness'. But it keeps your code behind clean and MVVM pattern in tact!