# Search in datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a textbox and what's typed in there must be searched in the datagrid.

Picture in the link for clarity.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8s98bes1g54xjaz/Search.png

I use the MVVM model.

```
XAML:
Textbox:

    <TextBox x:Name="txtZoeken" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="29" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="238" FontSize="20" Text="Zoeken..."/>

Datagrid:
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Contactpersons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="PersonenGrid" Grid.Column="1" Margin="35,99,8,10" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"  Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naam"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bedrijf" Binding="{Binding Company}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Functie" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding JobRole/Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stad" Binding="{Binding City}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="E-mail" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telefoon" Binding="{Binding Phone}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="GSM" Binding="{Binding Cellphone}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What are you looking to do with matching item(s)? For instance, Do you wish to limit your collection to show only the matching or to select the first matching item?

Comment: Anything is good really. Select the one that resembles closest or something.

Comment: If you are looking to multi select (want to fully control selections through your VMs) take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615271/wpf-datagrid-multiselect-binding on how to Bind a row selections to their respective VMs.

Comment: Nono, It has to selected the row that matches the closest search. I already have the match but now I want it to automatically select the row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an additional property within the ViewModel called SelectedPerson

```
        private Person_selectedperson;

        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedperson; }
            set
            {
                _selectedperson = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
            }
        }
```

This property should represent one instance within the collection of Contactpersons.  Then, bind this property to SelectedItem within the datagrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Contactpersons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
```

Then within your event/method related to the textbox search button.  Run a linq query or something similar to find the first match within the collection and set SelectedPerson to that item (I did it within a search click event while quickly writing the code, however, you may want to place in command in viewmodel to better adhere to mvvm)...

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string searchValue = textbox1.Text;
            vm.SelectedPerson = vm.Contactpersons.Where(a => a.LastName.Contains(searchValue)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

There will be additional error handling required beyond this example (checking if there is no matches etc)

Comment: This works! Thanks. But i want the datagrid to Select the line of the person it gets.